# How can I access props inside of Component in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I new to NextJS and React so I've setup a sample app to learn the ropes. I'm trying to access some props I passed to the component but they only seem to work outside of the `return()`. The following is the example component I have setup with an example of where I can access props and where I can't. Is there something I'm missing?

```
import React from 'react';
import { InlineTextarea, BlocksControls } from 'react-tinacms-inline'

export function HeroWithVideo({ 
            css_classes, 
            video_url, 
            poster_url, 
            muted, 
            loop, 
            playsinline, 
            autoplay 
}) {

// Works
console.log(muted)

return (
    <div
        className="mt-20 text-center max-w-6xl mx-auto"
    >
        {/* Doesn't Work */}
        {muted}
        <video>

        </video>
        <h1>
            <InlineTextarea name="heading" focusRing={false} />
       </h1>
    </div>
)
}

export const heroWithVideoBlock = {
Component: ({ index, data }) => (
  <BlocksControls
    index={index}
    focusRing={{ offset: 0 }}
    insetControls
>
    <HeroWithVideo {...data} />
  </BlocksControls>
),
template: {
    label: 'Hero with Video',
    defaultItem: {
        headline: 'Default Hero Headline',
    },
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'css_classes',
            label: 'CSS Classes',
            component: 'text',
        },
        {
            name: 'video_url',
            label: 'Video URL',
            component: 'text',
        },
        {
            name: 'muted',
            label: 'Muted',
            component: 'toggle',
        },
        {
            name: 'loop',
            label: 'Loop',
            component: 'toggle',
        },
        {
            name: 'playsinline',
            label: 'Plays Inline',
            component: 'toggle',
        },
        {
            name: 'autoplay',
            label: 'Autoplay',
            component: 'toggle',
        },

    ],
},
}
```

Comment: Well I was able to access the `muted` prop by using a conditional like so: ```{/* Now Works */}
            {muted && <>test</>}``` but when I try to apply with to my `<video {muted && <>muted</>}>` elements as a property is does not work. It throws and error: `Unexpected token, expected "..."`

Comment: Ok well it appears first of all I was using it wrong it needed to be `<video muted={muted} loop={loop}>` and second of all it appears that there is a bug with the muted parameter and react from back in 2016 and still around today, even though it doesn't show rendered in the DOM the parameter still works though. /shrug

Answer (score 0):

You should work in this way.

```
export function HeroWithVideo({...data}){

const {css_classes,video_url,poster_url,muted,loop,playsinline,autoplay } = data

}
```

then you can use these props easily like:

```
{muted ? <div> </div> : "" }

<div className={css_classes} />
```